# Why does the trailer object report a previous value for the "Size" entry?

Tags: pdfbox

I'm trying to write code that investigates changes to a PDF document after signing (pointers welcome) and came across this strange issue.

I want to retrieve the number of objects in the PDF file as indexed in the `xref` tables. It seems that, while all other entries in the trailer dictionary are that of the final trailer, the number for `Size` is the one on the original trailer. In my particular case there have been 2 updates to the original document (adding 2 xref tables for a total of 3), adding objects up to the number 567, from the original of 550.

This is how I get the `Size` from the trailer dictionary:

```java
  private static long getMaxObjId(PDDocument doc) {
    COSDocument cosdoc = doc.getDocument();
    COSDictionary trailer = cosdoc.getTrailer();
    long maxobj = trailer.getLong(COSName.SIZE);
    return maxobj;
  }
```

I'm using PDFBox 2.0.21.

Comment: Please also share your test PDF.

Comment: As an aside, I've meanwhile seen a number of pdfs with incorrect **Size** entries. Have you checked that with yours?

Comment: Can't share the PDF as it is of a sensitive nature. I'll see if I can find something similar elsewhere. `Size` entries are correct on each trailer.

Comment: Ok, found a file that has similar behavior, though it is linearized. Go to https://www.tecxoft.com/samples.php and download "[Sample 01]" (from "Single Signature Examples"). All signed samples I've tried (not related to this page; and I have plenty) make PDFBox exhibit the same problem.

Comment: I'll have a look next week, when I'm in office again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The **Size** entry in that *trailer* contains the lowest (i.e. usually the *oldest*) **Size** value of all trailers in the document while all other entries in that *trailer* contain the newest value of their respective keys.

And the cause for this is even worse than I originally thought: That *trailer* object you get is not simply the latest (or, considering the **Size** value, the earliest) **trailer** dictionary in the document, it is the union of all **trailer** dictionaries, starting with the earliest trailer in the **Prev** chain up to the newest one.

So far so good. But shouldn't this mean that all entries in that union trailer should have the value from the newest **trailer** dictionary with the entry key? That's what I thought until I saw the `COSDictionary.addAll(COSDictionary)` code used to create that union:

```java
/**
 * This will add all of the dictionaries keys/values to this dictionary.
 * Only called when adding keys to a trailer that already exists.
 *
 * @param dic The dictionaries to get the keys from.
 */
public void addAll(COSDictionary dic)
{
    dic.forEach((key, value) ->
    {
        /*
         * If we're at a second trailer, we have a linearized pdf file, meaning that the first Size entry represents
         * all of the objects so we don't need to grab the second.
         */
        if (!COSName.SIZE.equals(key) || !items.containsKey(COSName.SIZE))
        {
            setItem(key, value);
        }
    });
}
```

Here an existing **Size** entry is explicitly not replaced!

This explains the original observation that *the **Size** entry in that* trailer *contains the lowest (i.e. usually the *oldest*) **Size** value of all trailers in the document while all other entries in that* trailer *contain the newest value of their respective keys.*

The comments give rise to the assumption that this is a relic from the times when PDFBox by default parsed a PDF from the front, ignoring cross reference tables, and the only relevant test PDFs were ones without normal incremental updates, merely ones without updates at all and ones with linearization which uses mechanisms defined for incremental updates in inverse order. And only in case of such linearized documents this exception might make sense.

But why I consider this worse than originally thought: this `addAll` method is a public `COSDictionary` method which by its name parallels the Java Collection Framework `addAll`. Thus, it makes the user think the first JavaDoc line, `This will add all of the dictionaries keys/values to this dictionary`, is true; so he'll use it for that task, never expecting that **Size** entries won't be replaced.

Indeed, even in the PDFBox code itself `COSDictionary.addAll(COSDictionary)` is used in other context than for trailer unions in spite of the second JavaDoc line, `Only called when adding keys to a trailer that already exists.`

This should be inspected and fixed. I created a Jira issue to that effect, [PDFBOX-4999](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4999).